# How to decrease the distance between plotted points on x axis in R?

Tags: r, plot

I created this strip chart using the following code

```
stripchart(data=sub, Colabelled_Percent~Treatment, vertical=TRUE, 
           ylab='Co-labelled Percent', xlab='Treatment',
           group.names=c("mCherry", "miR-338-3p sensor" ))
```

but don't seem to be able to decrease the white space between my two Treatment groups.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust this using `xlim`.   Your two treatments are plotted at x=1 and x=2.  Use xlim to include more space. Since you don't provide your data, I illustrate with some sample data.

```
## Sample data 
x     = c(85,92,100, 35,50,80)
Treat = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B") 

stripchart(x ~ Treat, vertical=TRUE, xlim=c(0,3))
```

[image: Stripchart with extra space]